# How do I turn off source maps in production in Gatsby v2?

Tags: javascript, webpack, gatsby

I'm struggling how to disable source maps for production since the default Webpack set up is to leave out the devtool option, but Gatsby v2 is enabling it. I've tried coming up with a way based on the old version and the new docs, but it doesn't work:

```
// gatsby-node.js
exports.onCreateWebpackConfig = ({ actions, stage }) => {
  if (stage === 'build-javascript') {
    // turn off source-maps
    actions.setWebpackConfig({
      devtool: false
    })
  }
};
```

Comment: I did just find this smart workaround - You can modify your package.json file and append "&& rm build/**/*.map" to your build command.

Comment: so it looks like my solution in the question does work. either finder was not refreshing the file list or the build was not removing old sourcemap files

Comment: It should work — I use the same code, but without the condition.

Comment: Oh hey @ArtemSapegin! :) It does. Apparently the public folder is not deleted on each build so source maps I had previously created were still in there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The code in the question is the correct solution. The problem was that Gatsby does not delete the `/public/` folder on each build so previously created source maps were still there. So, first delete that folder, then run the build step.

Answer (score 5):

The above solution works. There is another option using gatsby plugin `gatsby-plugin-no-sourcemaps`

Install the plugin first

```
npm i gatsby-plugin-no-sourcemaps
```

After that goto `gatsby-config.js` in your project root.

Add this in plugins array

`gatsby-plugin-no-sourcemaps`

Goto to public folder, delete all file. Run build command again `gatsby build`. Now build will not have .map files.

`gatsby-config.js` will look like this.

[image]

Comment: but its also removes the map file in development. Any way to exclude the map files only in build and not while local development ?

Comment: @Nitin Looked into its source code, it's using `if (stage === 'build-javascript')` which only occurs in build stage (`gatsby build`).